# What is the proper way to do integration testing in Spring MVC and Hibernate based web aplication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, integration-testing, spring-test, dbunit

We have decided to implement integration tests in our web application. Web application is based on java, spring, spring MVC, hibernate and mysql.

When I did some research on it, I found out that lots of people are using dbunit. Another approach I found is that is using the embedded database like H2?

Rarely, I found out that people have used separate test db for integration testing.

So, what is the ideal way to setup database to do integration testing?

Comment: You'd better use the same database as the one used in production, otherwise you'll test that your app works fine on H2, although it doesn't run on H2 in production, but on MySQL, which is a completely different database. What's the point?

Comment: But the data in the live or dev db will keep on changing. So, how do we write tests against the changing data?

Comment: I am not sure, but is it possible to use the same db but some predefined/different data for the tests only?

Comment: You misinterpreted me. Don't use the same database instance. Use the same database product. I.e. use a local instance of MySQL, filled with test data. To set up test data, I'd use DbSetup. Disclaimer: I'm the author. http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Looking into dbsetup.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem like a good idea to keep the database you test against the same as what you intend to use in production, and it does have the advantage that all the issues that come up with will be relevant to the actual database used in production. But you're already using Hibernate as an abstraction layer between your code and the database, switching out the database the tests run against is possible.

An issue with using a non-embedded database in integration tests is that it can make it harder to run tests in Continuous Integration environments. Using an embedded database is a lot more convenient in that case because the database instance is specifically created, populated, and called only by the currently-running integration test, and you don't have possible issues with different processes accessing the same database and possibly changing data out from under each other.

Also, setting up the non-embedded database before the test run may increase the time taken to run the tests substantially, because the embedded database isn't saving anything to disk the setup doesn't take as long and the tests can run faster.

(This isn't an issue for MySQL, but embedded databases are an even more appealing choice when the database used in production is a proprietary one like Oracle where it's difficult to create new instances due to licensing.)

Using H2 and using DBUnit/DBSetup are not necessarily separate approaches, they are often used together. DBUnit and DBSetup are tools for populating the contents of the database so that the tests can execute against data in a known state. You can use either of them in combination with H2 so that the tests are location-independent (don't rely on an external shared database), execute quickly, and run against a well-defined data set. Regardless of whether you use an embedded database or not it's a good idea to use a tool like DBUnit or DbSetup to define explicitly what data the test will run against.

Comment: In the case of Hibernate/ORM the goal of integration testing would be to test the Mapping/Annotations and the entity beans, which represent the integration layer towards the database driver. Since hibernate promises to separate the concerns regarding the selection of the actual database vendor, he could indeed perform integration tests against a different database than the one he will use in production - unless he uses vendor specific configurations in his ORM layer of course.

Answer (score -1):

You use the phrase "integration testing" so maybe you do in fact want to be testing the database...but generally speaking you'd be better off testing your application code, not your DB driver.  To allow testing of application code that relies on a database, mocking tools like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) and [powermock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) give you the ability to fake the DB calls (you can have the DB methods return whatever you want) and allow you to write tests that focus on business logic.